# Educational games to master unix command line?

Tags: linux, command-line, game, educational, unix

Looking for recommendations, for some simple trainer style games to improve my command line skills.

Could be something similar to https://www.learnshell.org/, or even simpler. At the most basic level, I would be happy to just get a prompt, and feedback, doesn't have to be Ultima Ascension. :)

Comment: Just learned about https://www.codewars.com/?language=shell

Comment: Not a game but the book “Unix Power Tools” from O’Reilly And Associates helped get my career started. Many short sections each showing something useful. https://www.amazon.com/Power-Tools-Third-Shelley-Powers/dp/0596003307/ref=sr_1_1?keywords=Unix+power+tools&qid=1574625217&sr=8-1

Answer (score 2):

Not a game, but the Cisco NetAcad Linux book/course has an emulator built into it that is really really good, and can actually grade lab exercises.

But to keep it on topic, the games/fun stuff/challenges I recommend to my students are all from https://overthewire.org/wargames

Answer (score 2):

This page offers a web-based game (which you can download) to learn basic shell cmds:
Terminus, http://web.mit.edu/mprat/Public/web/Terminus/Web/main.html

Also find it on a link from her site:
http://www.mprat.org/projects/terminus/

There are open issues listed at her github site:
https://github.com/mprat/Terminus/issues?q=is%3Aopen

Or try searching for something like this: 
linux interactive bash shell tutorial game

Answer (score 0):

I have found a nice tool for this, even if it is not a game.

Enki app has a Linux track, with topics such as User & File management, Jobs, processes & data manipulation, Networking and security and so on. The modules explain how Linux systems work, and go over relevant commands for each topic. The lessons are free, and you can do quizzes with the premium version.